# HTML Fonts dont match on different elements

Tags: html, css

I have an `input` and `h4` element. I'm using the same font and font size but they do not look the same.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: sansReg;
  src: url(../fonts/openSansReg.ttf);
}

.global-message h4 {
  /*for the chat messages*/
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sansReg;
}

.input {
  /*for the chat message input*/
  padding-left: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sansReg;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  outline: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 2px 3px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="chat-box">
  <div id="chat-list-container">
    <ul id="chat-messages">
      <li class="global-message">
        <h4>Will: Anyone wanna play?</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="global-message">
        <h4>George: Hey guys!</h4>
      </li>
      <li class="global-message">
        <h4>Jessica: How do i start a game?</h4>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <input id="chat-message" class="input" type="text" placeholder="Message" maxlength="32" />
</div>
```

So as you can see I have some `h4`'s to fill the chat and my input below it and I have used the same font but it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I think the `font-weight` of the input is lighter than the normal elements, can you try adding `font-weight: bold !important;` to your input?

Comment: @lenilsondc ah! that was it, i wanted it the other way so i added that to the h4 and put lighter instead of normal. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `h4` element has `font-weight` `bold` by default; therefore, if you want to make the input look the same way, you have to add `font-weight: bold;` to your input style.

Or, if you want to make `h4` look like the `input`, you can remove the bold by setting it to normal `font-weight: normal;` on the `h4` element.

Examples:

```css
*{
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial;
}

.normal {
  font-weight: normal;
}

.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<h4>default bold</h4>
<h4 class="normal">light</h4>
<input value="default light"><br>
<input value="bold" class="bold"><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Headings have different default values. In your case you compare an h4 with a paragraph. As you can see below there is a big difference. What you need is to add `font-weight: bold;` to your `.input`-class.

**H4 default values**

```
h4 {
    display: block;
    font-size: 1em;
    margin-top: 1.33em;
    margin-bottom: 1.33em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Paragraph default values**

```
p {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

A "good" practice (or what I try to remember to do) is to copy all default values in for each CSS-element I create. By doing so I have access to all properties and not only those I want to change.

Answer (score 0):

Add css properties `font-weight: bold; font-size: 1em` to the input field. The font will look identical to the h4 font.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your css:

```
.global-message h4{
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

It should make all the font look the same.